# Poetry add dependecy from requirements.text fails NoSuchOptionException The "-r" option does not exist

Tags: dependency-management, python-poetry, requirements.txt

I want to add poetry to the existing project
to add a dependency from requirements.txt I ran the following command

```
poetry add $( cat requirements.txt )
```

In either case, I get the same error - shown below

```
.venv) bash-3.2$ poetry add $( cat requirements.txt )

  Stack trace:

  11  ~/.poetry/lib/poetry/_vendor/py3.8/clikit/console_application.py:123 in run
      io = io_factory(

  10  ~/.poetry/lib/poetry/console/config/application_config.py:221 in create_io
      resolved_command = application.resolve_command(args)

   9  ~/.poetry/lib/poetry/_vendor/py3.8/clikit/console_application.py:110 in resolve_command
      return self._config.command_resolver.resolve(args, self)

   8  ~/.poetry/lib/poetry/_vendor/py3.8/clikit/resolver/default_resolver.py:34 in resolve
      return self.create_resolved_command(result)

   7  ~/.poetry/lib/poetry/_vendor/py3.8/clikit/resolver/default_resolver.py:166 in create_resolved_command
      if not result.is_parsable():

   6  ~/.poetry/lib/poetry/_vendor/py3.8/clikit/resolver/resolve_result.py:43 in is_parsable
      self._parse()

   5  ~/.poetry/lib/poetry/_vendor/py3.8/clikit/resolver/resolve_result.py:49 in _parse
      self._parsed_args = self._command.parse(self._raw_args)

   4  ~/.poetry/lib/poetry/_vendor/py3.8/clikit/api/command/command.py:113 in parse
      return self._config.args_parser.parse(args, self._args_format, lenient)

   3  ~/.poetry/lib/poetry/_vendor/py3.8/clikit/args/default_args_parser.py:53 in parse
      self._parse(args, _fmt, lenient)

   2  ~/.poetry/lib/poetry/_vendor/py3.8/clikit/args/default_args_parser.py:103 in _parse
      self._parse_short_option(token, tokens, fmt, lenient)

   1  ~/.poetry/lib/poetry/_vendor/py3.8/clikit/args/default_args_parser.py:272 in _parse_short_option
      self._add_short_option(name, None, tokens, fmt, lenient)

  NoSuchOptionException

  The "-r" option does not exist.

  at ~/.poetry/lib/poetry/_vendor/py3.8/clikit/args/default_args_parser.py:349 in _add_short_option
      345│     def _add_short_option(
      346│         self, name, value, tokens, fmt, lenient
      347│     ):  # type: (str, Optional[str], List[str], ArgsFormat, bool) -> None
      348│         if not fmt.has_option(name):
    → 349│             raise NoSuchOptionException(name)
      350│ 
      351│         self._add_long_option(
      352│             fmt.get_option(name).long_name, value, tokens, fmt, lenient
      353│         )
```

for reference here is my requirement.txt

```
# This file is autogenerated by pip-compile with python 3.8
# To update, run:
#
#    pip-compile requirements.in
#
click==8.0.3
    # via -r requirements.in
gevent==21.8.0
    # via grequests
greenlet==1.1.2
    # via gevent
grequests==0.6.0
    # via -r requirements.in
idna==3.3
    # via requests
iniconfig==1.1.1
    # via pytest
```

Answer (score 4):

Looks like It was reading comments in requirements.txt

simple just ignore the comments run the following

```
cat requirements.txt|grep -v '#'|xargs poetry add
```